# Java's efficient imperative loop through Scala macros?

Tags: scala, macros, metaprogramming, scala-macros

Scala macros take well-typed terms as arguments instead of arbitrary AST, so it is not obvious to do certain things with them, in particular, introducing a new binding form.

Let's say I want to have a new Scala imperative for loop that desugars into tail recursion or a while loop. For example, this:

```
for_imp (i <- 1 to 10) {
  /* work */
}
```

would desugar to this:

```
{
   var i = 1
   while (i <= 10) {
     /* work */;
     i += 1
   }
}
```

or this:

```
@tailrec def loop(i: Int): Unit =
   if (i <= 10) {
      /* work */;
      loop(i + 1)
   }
loop(1)
```

Since we cannot introduce a new binding for `i`, would this approach make sense: make a new form `for-opt` that maps `expr[Unit]` to `expr[Unit]`; if its argument happens to have the right form of `for`, optimize it, otherwise leave it alone:

```
for_opt(e: expr[Unit]): expr[Unit] =
  e match {
    case /* for loop */ => /* transform */
    case e => e
  }
```

What would be a natural way to achieve Java's efficient imperative `for` loop in Scala?

Comment: Check out [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire)'s `cfor`, which does almost exactly what you're describing.

Comment: You may also be interested in this project: https://github.com/nativelibs4java/scalaxy-streams. it tries to do what you described - optimizes for comprehensions with macro

Comment: See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1338